# How to use public method in class using jquerymx

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about jquerymx.
I want to make public method that some method in deque class.
because It will be used to other class.
example) I think that pushback is private method in deque class. so I want to change it to public.
How can I solve this problem?

```
deque : function(){
   this.elements = [];

    // pushback :function(element)
    // {
    //      this.elements.push(element);
    // }

    this.push_back = function(element){
         this.elements.push(element);
    }

    this.push_front = function(element){
         this.elements.unshift(element);
    }

    this.pop_back = function(){
        return this.elements.pop();
    }

    this.pop_front = function() {
        return this.elements.shift();                                                
    }

    this.peek_back = function(){
         return this.elements[this.elements.length-1];
    }

    this.peek_front = function(){
         return this.elements[0];
    }

    this.isEmpty = function(){
         return this.elements.length === 0;
    }

    this.getElements = function(number){
         return this.elements[number];
    }

    this.Length = function(){
         return this.elements.length;
    }
}
```

Thanks any reply.

edit:

Widget.js

```
(function($,S){
 S.Claass('Widget',{
    init:function(){
    },
    deque : function(){
        this.elements = [];   

        push_back = (function(element){
            this.elements.push(element);
        }).bind(this);

        push_front = (function(element){
            this.elements.unshift(element);
        }).bind(this);

        pop_back = (function(){
            return this.elements.pop();
        }).bind(this);

        pop_front = (function() {
            return this.elements.shift();                                                
        }).bind(this);

        peek_back = (function(){
            return this.elements[this.elements.length-1];
        }).bind(this);

        peek_front = (function(){
            return this.elements[0];
        }).bind(this);

        isEmpty = (function(){
            return this.elements.length === 0;
        }).bind(this);

        getElements = (function(number){
            return this.elements[number];
        }).bind(this);

        Length = (function(){
            return this.elements.length;
        }).bind(this);
    });
})(jQuery, ...);
```

------.js

```
(function($, S){
   S.Widget('-----',{
      init:function(){
         this.tempDeque = new this.deque();
      },

      setup:function(){
          ....

         for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
               .....
              this.tempDeque.push_back(i); /// this is error.
         }
      }
   });

})(jQuery, ...);
```

Comment: `pushback  = (function(element)
    {
          this.elements.push(element);
     }).bind(this);` making it available on global scope once `deque ` function has been called. Not sure it is what you are looking for. But you could `return this;` from deque function and then access all relative methods

Comment: Console.log is "Cannot call method 'push_back' of undefined". It is error. push_back = (function(element){
    this.elements.push(element);
   }).bind(this); I Write this.

Comment: See Edit line. I changed to your advise but return error.